# Hide text lines/text patterns from a generated logfile

Tags: file, text, cmd, scripting, hide

As my role as tester (among all the things), I need to review log files for errors. Unfortunatly, the generated output file (file-YYYY-MM-DD.log) displays all kinds of information, not just the errors (or "things that go bad").

My question is; how do I hide the lines I don't want and generate an output file (log) containing the deviations (errors, warnings etc)?

For example, I want to hide:

```
 | I | variable text I do not want, location: /path/to/foo/bar

 | W | service X stopped

 | W | service X started
```

The most ideal outcome with the script I want is:

```
-> Ask question: "Do you want to hide information and warning messages?   |

-> Answer: yes --> hide all | I | message (like: no new foo's found in:                   /location/to/foo. 

-> Answer: no --> do nothing (closes script)
```

The data is from an Unix environment, however the script is going to run in an Windows environment.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at the [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) commands. (watch for the `/v` switch)

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: It kinda works.
Not the end result I want, but I go and try some commands with the find and findstr... Thanks for the reply Stephan